# Is there a well-known file format to store data and data changes made to file?

Tags: git, file, file-format

Actually I would like to export changes made to a github project to look at them in future. I don't want to commit them. Right now I do

```
git diff >> change1.txt
```

then modify my change and run the command again

```
git diff >> change2.txt
```

the problem here is that I cannot view the changes in a beautiful colorful previews like VS Code or 'git diff' can show me. One way is to convert colored view of the terminal to a html view but in that case it becomes hard to work with the real code from the html code.

Comment: There are several related formats to represent [patches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_(Unix)) (also sometimes just called a diff). And various tools can syntax-highlight that. But a patch alone doesn't have all the information to give you a nice before/after view, because it only includes changed lines (and possibly some context around those changes).

Comment: If you don't need context but really just the line differences with a bit of color, you can save the output with `.diff` extension and majority of editors will open it in a nice way but this will be far from the experience you have with context.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) : one way to "store but not in a branch" changes is to run :

```
git stash && git stash apply

# if you want to add a more excpliicit message to your stash :
git stash push -m "my message"
git stash apply
```

At a later time, you can run `git stash list` to view the list of items in your stash, and compare your local changes to one of your stashes :

```
git diff stash      # to compare your changes to your latest stash
git diff stash@{0}  # exact equivalent of the above
git diff stash@{5}  # to compare with an older stash listed in 'git stash list'
```

Comment: stash is a temporary solution. what I am looking for is to have something like git diff stash but what I can view in years later.